# Graph generation of CPU and Memory uses of a process in performance testing on linux

Tags: performance, graph

I perform performance testing so after completion of performance testing i need to find out the cpu , memory , network and i/o uses by a process.Also I want to represent all this values in graphicaly using python. What are the tools avilable in Python  by which i can genrates these things.